# How to make fancy tables in latex?

Tags: tables

I want to draw a table given below as it is

[image]

I don't how to make it properly. I can make a table like this given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llcr}
\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Class} & \textbf{Occupy} & \textbf{Run Time} \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}RM FM RF\\ FMKMRKF\\ MLRFKR\end{tabular} & R &  \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & RM F & R & R \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & FRR & R &  \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}CKRMKMR\\ F MRMR\\ FR M\end{tabular} & R4 & R \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & RF &  &  \\ \cline{2-4} 
 & FRFRMMK & 4R & 4 \\ \cline{2-4} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which gives a table but very different looking then the expected. Some of the things I am not able to achieve is colors, solid lines etc.

**Question :** How to make a table given in the image?

Comment: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and `\rowcolor` statements... see the manual of `colortbl` please, which is loaded by the `table` option of `xcolor`

Comment: Please have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mrh{\color{white}\bfseries}
\newcommand\mrc[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{gray!10}} l | c|r}
    \rowcolor{gray}
\mrh{Class}  & \mrh{Occupy}   & \mrh{Run Time}    \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
\mrc{RM FM RF\\ FMKMRKF\\ MLRFKR}
                & R                 &                       \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
RM F            & R                 & R                     \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
FRR             & R                 &                       \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
\mrc{CKRMKMR\\ F MRMR\\ FR M}
                & R4                & R                     \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
RF              &                   &                       \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
FRFRMMK         & 4R                & 4
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}


\newcommand{\minitab}[2][1]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\arrayrulecolor{white}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[RGB]{96,96,96}       &       &       &  \\
    \rowcolor[RGB]{96,96,96} \multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{1}}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{$\bm{c_{k}}$}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{All optimal solutions} \\ \textbf{must satisfy}}}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Max values of coins}\\ \textbf{1,2,…,k-1 in any OPT}}}}\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[RGB]{203,203,203} $\bm{1}$ & $\bm{1}$ & $\bm{P\leq4}$ & $\bm{-}$ \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[RGB]{203,203,203} $\bm{2}$ & $\bm{5}$ & $\bm{N\leq1}$ & $\bm{4}$ \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[RGB]{203,203,203} $\bm{3}$ & $\bm{10}$ & $\bm{N+D\leq2}$ & $\bm{4+5=9}$ \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[RGB]{203,203,203} $\bm{4}$ & $\bm{25}$ & $\bm{Q\leq3}$ & $\bm{20+4=24}$ \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[RGB]{203,203,203} $\bm{5}$ & $\bm{100}$ & \textbf{no limit} & $\bm{75+24=99}$ \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]